# custom resolution type in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, resolution, issue-tracking

Can we create custom resolution type in SonarQube like we have unresolved, false positive etc ?
I have checked sonar documentation but nothing is available for the same.
Is there any other work around for it?

Comment: To get a workaround, you'll need to [edit] your question to include your use case/reason for wanting a custom resolution.

Answer (score 0):

No, resolutions can't be extended.